# How to keep the instantiated objects on the terrain to be inside the terrain area?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

some of the objects instantiated on the edge/s of the terrain half inside half outside.

in this case the terrain width is 1000 and the terrain length is 500.
but it happens on any size of the terrain even if the size is. 1000,1000

the script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class InstantiateOnTerrain : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float terrainWidth;
    private float terrainLength;

    private float xTerrainPos;
    private float zTerrainPos;

    public Terrain terrain;
    public GameObject prefab;
    public int numberOfObjects;
    public float yOffset;


    void Start()
    {
        //Get terrain size
        terrainWidth = terrain.terrainData.size.x;
        terrainLength = terrain.terrainData.size.z;

        //Get terrain position
        xTerrainPos = terrain.transform.position.x;
        zTerrainPos = terrain.transform.position.z;

        generateObjectOnTerrain();
    }

    void generateObjectOnTerrain()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++)
        {
            //Generate random x,z,y position on the terrain
            float randX = UnityEngine.Random.Range(xTerrainPos, xTerrainPos + terrainWidth);
            float randZ = UnityEngine.Random.Range(zTerrainPos, zTerrainPos + terrainLength);
            float yVal = Terrain.activeTerrain.SampleHeight(new Vector3(randX, 0, randZ));

            //Apply Offset if needed
            yVal = yVal + yOffset;


            //Generate the Prefab on the generated position
            GameObject objInstance = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(randX, yVal, randZ), Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: terrain]

the object that is on the edge:

sometimes it's one object sometimes more on the edge/s.

[image: object on the edge]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to account for the size of the object as well.

```
float objOffsetX = prefab.transform.localScale.x / 2;
float objOffsetZ = prefab.transform.localScale.z / 2;

float randX = UnityEngine.Random.Range(xTerrainPos + objOffsetX, xTerrainPos + terrainWidth - objOffsetX);
float randZ = UnityEngine.Random.Range(zTerrainPos + objOffsetZ, zTerrainPos + terrainLength - objOffsetZ);
```

The pivot is in the center of the object, offset half of the objects width and length when placing on the terrain.